DDP on 8 GPUs Freezes During Training with Transformer Model—Need Help Diagnosing the Issue
I have a basic machine translation transformer model that worked well on a single GPU. However, when I tried running it on an 8-GPU setup using DDP, I initially encountered many crashes due to data not being properly transferred to the correct GPUs. I believe I've resolved those issues, and the model now runs, but only up to a certain point.
Here is my training function:
def train(rank, world_size):
    ddp_setup(rank, world_size)

    torch.manual_seed(0)

    SRC_VOCAB_SIZE = len(vocab_transform[SRC_LANGUAGE])
    TGT_VOCAB_SIZE = len(vocab_transform[TGT_LANGUAGE])

    EMB_SIZE = 512
    NHEAD = 8
    FFN_HID_DIM = 1024
    BATCH_SIZE = 128
    NUM_ENCODER_LAYERS = 3
    NUM_DECODER_LAYERS = 3

    LOAD_MODEL = False
    if LOAD_MODEL:
        transformer = torch.load("model/_transformer_model")
    else:
        transformer = Seq2SeqTransformer(NUM_ENCODER_LAYERS, NUM_DECODER_LAYERS, EMB_SIZE,
                                         NHEAD, SRC_VOCAB_SIZE, TGT_VOCAB_SIZE, FFN_HID_DIM)

        for p in transformer.parameters():
            if p.dim() > 1:
                nn.init.xavier_uniform_(p)

    transformer.move_positional_encoding_to_rank(rank)  # moving positional_encoding into the current GPU

    # Create the dataset
    train_dataset = SrcTgtDatasetFromFiles(SRC_TRAIN_BASE, TGT_TRAIN_BASE, FILES_COUNT_TRAIN)

    # create a DistributedSampler for data loading
    train_sampler = DistributedSampler(train_dataset, num_replicas=world_size, rank=rank)

    # create a DataLoader with the DistributedSampler
    # train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, sampler=train_sampler)
    train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, pin_memory=True,
                                  collate_fn=collate_fn, sampler=train_sampler)

    # create the model and move it to the GPU with the device ID
    model = transformer.to(rank)
    model.train()  # set the model into training mode with dropout etc.

    # wrap the model with DistributedDataParallel
    model = DDP(model, device_ids=[rank])

    loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=PAD_IDX)

    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001, betas=(0.9, 0.98), eps=1e-9)

    for state in optimizer.state.values():
        for k, v in state.items():
            if torch.is_tensor(v):
                state[k] = v.to(rank)

    #######################################
    EPOCHS_NUM = 2

    for epoch in range(EPOCHS_NUM):
        epoch_start_time = int(timer())
        print("\n\nepoch number: " + str(epoch + 1) + "  Rank: " + str(rank))

        losses = 0.0
        idx = 0
        start_time = int(timer())
        for src, tgt in train_dataloader:
            if rank == 0:
                print("rank=" + str(rank) + " idx=" + str(idx))

            src = src.to(rank)
            tgt = tgt.to(rank)

            tgt_input = tgt[:-1, :]

            if IS_DEBUG:
                print("rank", rank, "idx", idx, "before create_mask")
            src_mask, tgt_mask, src_padding_mask, tgt_padding_mask = create_mask(src, tgt_input, rank)
            if IS_DEBUG:
                print("rank", rank, "idx", idx, "after create_mask")

            if IS_DEBUG:
                print("rank",rank,"idx",idx,"before model")
            logits = model(src, tgt_input, src_mask, tgt_mask, src_padding_mask, tgt_padding_mask, src_padding_mask)
            if IS_DEBUG:
                print("rank", rank, "idx", idx, "after model")

            try:

                if IS_DEBUG:
                    print("rank",rank,"idx",idx,"before zero_grad")
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                if IS_DEBUG:
                    print("rank",rank,"idx",idx,"after zero_grad")

                tgt_out = tgt[1:, :].long()

                if IS_DEBUG:
                    print("rank",rank,"idx",idx,"before loss_fn")
                loss = loss_fn(logits.reshape(-1, logits.shape[-1]), tgt_out.reshape(-1))
                if IS_DEBUG:
                    print("rank",rank,"idx",idx,"after loss_fn")

                if IS_DEBUG:
                    print("rank",rank,"idx",idx,"before backward")
                loss.backward()
                if IS_DEBUG:
                    print("rank",rank,"idx",idx,"after backward")

                # Delete unnecessary variables before backward pass
                del src, tgt_input, src_mask, tgt_mask, src_padding_mask, tgt_padding_mask, logits, tgt_out
                torch.cuda.empty_cache()  # Clear cache after deleting variables


                if IS_DEBUG:
                    print("rank",rank,"idx",idx,"before step")
                optimizer.step()
                if IS_DEBUG:
                    print("rank",rank,"idx",idx,"after step")

                losses += loss.item()

                #######################################
                # print(999,rank,loss)

                # Free GPU memory
                del loss
                torch.cuda.empty_cache()  # Clear cache after each batch
            except Exception as e:
                print("An error occurred: rank=" + str(rank) + " idx=" + str(idx))
                print("Error message: ", str(e))

            idx += 1

            if rank == 0 and idx % 10000 == 0:
                torch.save(model.module.state_dict(), "model/_transformer_model")
                end_time = int(timer())
                try:
                    my_test(model.module, rank, SRC_TEST_BASE, TGT_TEST_BASE, FILES_COUNT_TEST, epoch, 0,
                            0, int((end_time - start_time) / 60), epoch_start_time)
                except:
                    print("error occurred test")
                start_time = int(timer())

            # Synchronize training across all GPUs
            torch.distributed.barrier()

        if rank == 0:
            epoch_end_time = int(timer())
            try:
                my_test_and_save_to_file(model.module, rank, SRC_TEST_BASE, FILES_COUNT_TEST, epoch)
                loss = evaluate(model.module, rank, SRC_VAL_BASE, TGT_VAL_BASE, FILES_COUNT_VAL, BATCH_SIZE,
                                loss_fn)
                print("EPOCH NO." + str(epoch) + " Time: " + str(int((epoch_end_time - epoch_start_time) / 60)) +
                      " LOSS:" + str(loss))
            except:
                print("error occurred evaluation")

    destroy_process_group()

When I run it I recieve this output:

Let's use 8 GPUs! Let's use 8 GPUs! Let's use 8 GPUs! Let's use 8
GPUs! Let's use 8 GPUs! Let's use 8 GPUs! Let's use 8 GPUs! Let's use
8 GPUs!
epoch number: 1  Rank: 0 rank=0 idx=0
rank 0 idx 0 before create_mask
epoch number: 1  Rank: 1
rank 0 idx 0 after zero_grad rank 0 idx 0
before model rank 1 idx 0 before create_mask
epoch number: 1  Rank: 3
epoch number: 1  Rank: 2
epoch number: 1  Rank: 4
epoch number: 1  Rank: 6
epoch number: 1  Rank: 5
epoch number: 1  Rank: 7
rank 1 idx 0 after zero_grad
rank 1 idx 0 before model
rank 3 idx 0 before create_mask
rank 4 idx 0 before create_mask
rank 2 idx 0 before create_mask
rank 6 idx 0 before create_mask
rank 7 idx 0 before create_mask
rank 5 idx 0 before create_mask
rank 3 idx 0 after zero_grad
rank 3 idx 0 before model
rank 4 idx 0 after zero_grad
rank 4 idx 0 before model
rank 2 idx 0 after zero_grad
rank 2 idx 0 before model
rank 7 idx 0 after zero_grad
rank 7 idx 0 before model
rank 6 idx 0 after zero_grad
rank 6 idx 0 before model
rank 5 idx 0 after zero_grad
rank 5 idx 0 before model
rank 0 idx 0 after model
rank 0 idx 0 before zero_grad
rank 0 idx 0 after zero_grad
rank 0 idx 0 before loss_fn
rank 0 idx 0 after loss_fn
rank 0 idx 0 before backward
rank 4 idx 0 after model
rank 4 idx 0 before zero_grad
rank 4 idx 0 after zero_grad
rank 4 idx 0 before loss_fn
rank 4 idx 0 after loss_fn
rank 4 idx 0 before backward
rank 1 idx 0 after model
rank 1 idx 0 before zero_grad
rank 1 idx 0 after zero_grad
rank 1 idx 0 before loss_fn
rank 1 idx 0 after loss_fn
rank 1 idx 0 before backward
rank 5 idx 0 after model
rank 5 idx 0 before zero_grad
rank 5 idx 0 after zero_grad
rank 5 idx 0 before loss_fn
rank 7 idx 0 after model
rank 7 idx 0 before zero_grad
rank 7 idx 0 after zero_grad
rank 7 idx 0 before loss_fn
rank 5 idx 0 after loss_fn
rank 5 idx 0 before backward
rank 7 idx 0 after loss_fn
rank 7 idx 0 before backward
rank 3 idx 0 after model
rank 3 idx 0 before zero_grad
rank 3 idx 0 after zero_grad
rank 3 idx 0 before loss_fn
rank 3 idx 0 after loss_fn
rank 3 idx 0 before backward
rank 2 idx 0 after model
rank 2 idx 0 before zero_grad
rank 2 idx 0 after zero_grad
rank 2 idx 0 before loss_fn
rank 2 idx 0 after loss_fn
rank 2 idx 0 before backward
rank 6 idx 0 after model
rank 6 idx 0 before zero_grad
rank 6 idx 0 after zero_grad
rank 6 idx 0 before loss_fn
rank 6 idx 0 after loss_fn
rank 6 idx 0 before backward
rank 3 idx 0 after backward
rank 5 idx 0 after backward
rank 7 idx 0 after backward
rank 0 idx 0 after backward
rank 4 idx 0 after backward
rank 6 idx 0 after backward
rank 2 idx 0 after backward
rank 1 idx 0 after backward
rank 0 idx 0 before step
rank 0 idx 0 after step
rank=0 idx=1
rank 0 idx 1 before create_mask
rank 0 idx 1 after zero_grad
rank 0 idx 1 before model
rank 0 idx 1 after model
rank 0 idx 1 before zero_grad
rank 0 idx 1 after zero_grad
rank 0 idx 1 before loss_fn
rank 0 idx 1 after loss_fn
rank 0 idx 1 before backward

After that, the program freezes.
When I hit the break button I get this messages:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main-spacy-16-DDP.py",
line 610, in 
mp.spawn(train, args=(WORLD_SIZE,), nprocs=WORLD_SIZE)   File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py",
line 230, in spawn
return start_processes(fn, args, nprocs, join, daemon, start_method='spawn')   File
"/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py",
line 188, in start_processes
while not context.join():   File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py",
line 101, in join
timeout=timeout,   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 911, in wait
ready = selector.select(timeout)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/selectors.py", line 376, in select
fd_event_list = self._poll.poll(timeout) KeyboardInterrupt

I’ve spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, but I’m stuck and can’t pinpoint what’s causing the issue or how to proceed. Does anyone have any suggestions?
